# Зачем нужны объекты в написании программ?

Tags: java, ооп

Вопрос следующий, для чего нужны объекты в написании программ? Зачем создавать что-то отдельное, если можно добавлять static методы? Погуглив немного, наткнулся на пример - продукты в магазине, есть класс Product и объекты этого класса - более конкретно описанные продукты. НО зачем создавать отдельные объекты класса Product, если можно сделать несколько классов наследников Product, например Juice extends Product, AppleJuice extends Juice и так далее, расписывая нюансы непосредственно в классах. Заранее спасибо

Comment: "Зачем создавать что-то отдельное, если можно добавлять static методы?" - зачем нужны отдельные экземпляры книг, если есть книжные магазины?

Comment: а как ты потом сделаешь себе корзину с продуктами?

Comment: Вопрос грамотный. Ответ: это лишь вопрос удобства. Java так задумана и спроектирована чтобы объекты были самым удобным средством решения задач.

Comment: Вопрос не так прост, как кажется, и я не вижу причин его минусовать. Не могу уверенно сказать, хороший ли это воапрос именно для SO, но почему бы и нет. Есть много обоснованных аргументов в пользу ООП, и есть некоторое количество не менее обоснованной критики ООП. Хороший ответ на такой вопрос, вероятно, может включать и то, и другое.

Comment: Так и будешь в коде для каждого сока прописывать отдельный класс? А когда что-то новое на склад подвезут, будешь переписыаать софт? Зачем создавать отдельные классы, которые нужно заранее описывать в коде, когда можно одним классом описать много разных, но сходных сущностей?

Comment: Программировать можно по разному, ООП это один из способов. Есть процедурные языки, такие как С или Pascal. Тогда незачем использовать Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0. [ООП](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) вообще - это (спорная, но такая уж она есть) попытка "эмулировать реальный мир" программными средствами. Основными правилами такой эмуляции становится вот что: экземпляры объектов - это как экземпляры "предметов реального мира", при этом все экземпляры одного класса соответствуют предметам, относящимся к одному "классу" в реальном мире. Свойства экземпляра ("поля") - это характеристика реального предмета. Методы экземпляра - это как бы "действия", которые можно делать с предметом.

Классический пример - это класс Car, (автомобиль), у которого есть такие характеристики, как фирма - произодитель, цвет, количество дверей, ёмкость бензобака, кол-во бензина в баке, расход на 100 км, скорость и т.п. Примером метода может быть "заправить" или "залить столько то литров в бак" (вообще хороший пример, потому что может возращать exception при превышении объема бака) , в результате чего  у экземпляра объекта поменяется свойство "кол-во бензина в баке"

1. Давайте в качестве первого шага разберем разницу между классом и экземпляром класса. Класс - это как бы "обобщенный автомобиль". Экземпляр - это "конкретный автомобиль" - маленький мерседес-купе 520-й модели, небесно голубого цвета.
2. Всё дальнейшее в ООП - происходит уже из практики программирования и решения практических задач. Как оказывается, есть много случаев, когда нужно создавать классы с похожей функциональностью. Тогда используется наследование, композиция, и т.п. На эту тему есть, по моему, прекрасная [статья](https://intellect.icu/osnovnye-ponyatiya-oop-kratko-klass-obekt-abstragirovanie-inkapsulyatsiya-polimorfizm-nasledovanie-4441) - это, можно сказать, "описание всего ООП в миниатюре".
3. Критике ООП подхода почти столько же лет, как самому подходу. Классической уже стала фраза "Вам нужен был банан, но вы получили гориллу, держащую банан, и целые джунгли впридачу." (по моему, это слова Джо Армстронга, создателя языка Эрланг).
4. Мне нравится, что терминология ООП проникла в художественную литературу: в книге "Рабы Майкрософта" Дуглас Коупленд [пишет](https://knizhnik.org/duglas-kouplend/raby-microsoft/12) (словами одного из своих героев): "«Ооп!» — это виртуальный конструктор. Бездонная коробка объемных блоков, похожих на лего..."

Ну, и для настроения - картинка на тему:

[image: Полиморфизм, инкапсуляция, наследование]

Answer (score 1):

Можно.
Но тогда у тебя будет по одной сущности на класс. Два одинаковых хлеба ты сделать не сможешь.
Классы на то и созданы, чтобы быть некой абстракцией с конкретностью, ограниченной лишь самими параметрами класса и некоторой реализацией (что отличает классы от интерфейсов).

Статические методы и свойства - особый тип. На проде их использование трижды обдумывается.

Таким образом, если тебе требуется лишь один экземпляр класса, который и классом то назвать язык не поворачивается (например, какой-нибудь идемпотентный маппер), можешь смело прибегнуть к статике.

А вообще, согласен с ответом выше. Но хотел как-то разжевать и упростить его.

Comment: Супер. Ваш ответ - конкретнее и понятнее моего. Спасибо!